# Summerhouse door hinge repair/replacement

Tags: doors, hinges

My wife and I recently purchased a house that came with a summerhouse in the back garden. It's brilliant having it there, very useful and I have started working on the internals (installing a bar and making it a place for gatherings once lockdown is over!)

I want to now focus on the externals. Specifically the door and window. The window won't open due to the top dropping, and the doors do not shut correctly due to dropping too. Fortunately, I can still lock it! The hinges are not in great condition, but they are ones I haven't seen before so I'm not sure how to fix them or replace them.

The hinges look like this:

[image]

[image]

Here is a closer look at how the hinges connect to the door and door frame:

[image]

[image]

This is a front view of the doors, showing how they have dropped (and thus do not close)

[image]

[image]

[image]

And finally, the window uses the same hinges as seen here:

[image]

I' like to eventually replace the doors when I have the money, but for now I'd like to repair or replace the hinges just to get the windows and doors functioning properly again.

If anyone can let me know how to do this as I have never see these hinges before and can't see how I would get to them as there is no visible plate where they screw into the frame.

If more pictures or information is required, please let me know.

Comment: Can you lift the door separating to two parts of the hinge and then unscrew each piece of the hinge from the wood frame/door?

Comment: @JACK I have tried lifting it, but it doesn't budge. Unless it is just sticking with rust and/or age? Do these hinges screw in separately then one drops in to the other?

Comment: I have removed some very similar that did just that.

Comment: @JACK if that's the case, do you know what these types of hinges are called, or a link to where they can be purchased so I can have some replacements ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at a screw in, lift off  barrel pin hinge.

[image]

The one shown above has a set screw to prevent unnecessary lift off, yours might not have it.

There are better hinges out there for door and windows that are more available so look around. These hinges are going to be hard to find at your regular home stores. You'll need a speciality store unless you can reuse the ones you have and just mount them in new holes.

Spray some liquid wrench in them and then work them out... you might have to get rough...

Comment: Lovely. Thank you. I'll have a look out for these at the weekend, or get different style hinges

Comment: @MCG It may be worth hitting them with some sort of penetrating oil today, then letting them soak until you get to the actual disassembly over the weekend. If they don't want to pivot well, it may be worth 2minutes to give it a hit of oil _every_ evening until you can a chance to actually work on them. If they're that old...

Comment: @FreeMan good idea. I only have WD40 so I'll use tht

Comment: @MCG 3-4 applications of WD40 will likely get you where you need to be. For future reference, there are better products for more of a "I need it loose and I need it loose NOW" situation. Stop by your local auto parts store for a recommendation. (Product recommendations are OT 'round here, so I'll avoid naming names.)